# Stochastic Gradient Decent for L2 Log Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent, stochastic

I was trying to code SGD for L2 Log Regression in Python. But my avg loss is remaining almost the same for every epoch. Can some one help me out with the code.
Code:
Function to predict the Y

```
def predict(row, coefficients):
    yhat = coefficients[0]
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        yhat += coefficients[i + 1] * row[i]
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-yhat))
```

Function to calculate the loss

```
def loss_func(w,x_i,lam):
    y=x_i['y']
    yhat=predict(x_i[:-1],w)
    loss=(y*np.log(yhat))-((1-y)*np.log(1-yhat))+(lam*np.linalg.norm(w)/2)
    return loss
```

Function to update weights

```
def weights(w,x,lrate,n_epoch,lam):
    total_loss_lst=[0,1]
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        sum_error=0
        total_loss=0
        for k in range(len(x)):
            x_i=x.iloc[k]
            total_loss+=loss_func(w,x_i,lam)

        each_row=x.iloc[np.random.randint(len(x))]
        y_pred=predict(each_row[:-1],w)
        error=y_pred-each_row['y']
        w[0]=w[0]+(lrate*error)
        for i in range(0,len(each_row)-1):
            #print(each_row[i])
            w[i+1]=w[i+1]-(lrate*error*y_pred*(1-y_pred)*each_row[i])
            #w[i+1]=w[i+1]+(lrate*error*each_row[i])
        total_loss_lst.append(total_loss/len(x))
        print('>epoch=%d, lrate=%.3f, error=%.3f' % (epoch, lrate, total_loss/len(x)))
    return w
```

Initiating the function w vector is all zero at first instance.

```
weights(w,x,.0001,10,.0001)
```

I am getting the below output.

```
>epoch=0, lrate=0.000, error=0.274
>epoch=1, lrate=0.000, error=0.274
>epoch=2, lrate=0.000, error=0.274
>epoch=3, lrate=0.000, error=0.274
>epoch=4, lrate=0.000, error=0.274
>epoch=5, lrate=0.000, error=0.275
>epoch=6, lrate=0.000, error=0.275
>epoch=7, lrate=0.000, error=0.275
>epoch=8, lrate=0.000, error=0.275
>epoch=9, lrate=0.000, error=0.275
```

The weights are getting updated but the loss is very similar. But the sklearn's loss output is ranging from .45 to .37.

Thank you

Comment: Have you added a bias ?

Comment: multiply loss with (-1/N) for first part, not penality